# PHP insert Array with stdclass to MySQL

Tags: php, arrays

```
    array(115) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (13) {
    ["_id"]=>
    string(24) "57074056e4b03cad2f940060"
    ["admin_name"]=>
    string(5) "ramil"
    ["code"]=>
    string(10) "3596495399"
    ["duration"]=>
    int(1440)
  }

  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (13) {
    ["_id"]=>
    string(24) "57074056e4b03cad2f94005f"
    ["admin_name"]=>
    string(5) "ramil"
    ["code"]=>
    string(10) "7860239069"
    ["duration"]=>
    int(1440)
  }
  }
  ..........
  ..........
```

This is a hotspot voucher.

```
var_dump ($data); //sample output above.
```

i'm having problem inserting this to the db. i just started PHP btw the $data is called from API.

This is the success implode for array $data.

```
$array=array($data_convert);
$value=implode(" ",$array);
echo $value;

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

> How to loop and inserting to the db.?

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: _which is looping_ - where? where's the loop? how do you work with `$data`? what's your problem?

Comment: This is the success implode $array=array($data_convert);
$value=implode(" ",$array);
echo $value;

Comment: loops => https://www.howtoforge.com/loops_in_php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have $data you have to loop it using this:

```
<?php
    ...
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    foreach($data as $k => $v){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (id,admin_name,code,duration) VALUES (" . $v->_id . "," . $v->admin_name . "," . $v->code . "," . $v->duration . ")";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
?>
```

You have a object array so you have to enter in every object, get the values and insert into the database.

Comment: I'm getting this error upon compiling your code simon "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'b03cad2f940060,ramil,3596495399,1440)' at line 1Error: INSERT INTO"

Comment: NaD, the query is demostrative. You have to change my query with your query but keeping the $v references. Example: create a table with id,admin_name,code,duration. Call it "user". Change and replace in my SQL " table_name " with "user".

Comment: If you have autoincrement id don't use $v->_id. Use "null"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
function insert_data($dataObj){

  foreach($dataObj as $data){

      if(is_object($data)){
          // return field values and name as string 
          //something like this- (sn, answer) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2])
          $fieldValueString = $this->_array_to_string($data);

          $queryString = "INSERT INTO <tablename> $fieldValueString";

          //Execute query
          return $this->_link->query($queryString ); 
      }
   }<!-- ./foreach -->
}
```

Supporting Function:

```
public function _array_to_string($array){
    //Fetch where condition in a string
    $string = "";

    if($array !="" && count($array) >0){ 
        //Fetch fileds
        $dataArrayField = array();
        //Fetch values
        $dataArrayValue = array();

        foreach($filedsValue as $field => $value){ 
           $dataArrayValue[] = $value; 
           $dataArrayField[] = $field; 
        }

    $string = "( ".implode(", ", $dataArrayField)." ) VALUES ( '".implode("', '", $dataArrayValue)."' )";
    }
    return $string;
}
```